# Error when trying to precompile assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy an application. I've deployed this app before, but for some reason it's now failing to precompile assets.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production /tmp/myapp/rvm-auto.sh . bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (): [/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby ...]
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:54:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: That's a really weird error. Can you try changing Ruby to lower version? (2.0 or even 1.9.)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991365/command-failed-with-status-when-precompiling-assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to increase the memory for deployment

I had this problem before when deploying to AWS Beanstalk which was using an EC2 instance with 1GB Ram (but actually only 30% of it was using for deployment). I upgraded to 2GB and everything backs to work!

Comment: I ended up creating adding "swap" and it worked now. I could see when trying to run the command on the server directly the process was getting killed for some reason. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04